# Upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 but downgrading the edition - will this cause problems?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking at upgrading our SQL Servers from 2005 **Enterprise** edition to SQL Server 2008 R2 **Standard** edition.

Obviously, the upgrade to 2008 R2 gives us more features even in Standard edition, but I am wondering what features will be lost by going from Enterprise down to Standard, if any.

I've tried searching around for this but there are only comparisons between editions on the same version (i.e. 2008 Standard vs Enterprise) not comparasions between different editions across different versions (i.e. 2005 Enterprise vs 2008 Standard).

Anyone got any advice or has any resource they can point me at?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Very few SQL language features are different between editions.

Some language constructs (CREATE PARTITION for example and related) are additional (as opposed to different) and won't work because these are Enterprise features.

However, for day to day code, nothing special, things are almost identical.

The only thing I can recall that is different is how [indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181151.aspx) are used

Comment: I think you can only do a 2 node cluster with Standard.  You might also lose out on some of the higher end HA features.  These things might not matter though.

Answer (score 2):

You can cross reference and compare the features for [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143761%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with the features in [2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

As far as advice... if you are using features that are not available in SQL Server 2005 Standard, then you'll need to verify that those features are in SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be loosing things like online index rebuilds, partitioning, and some features like the ability to automatically use an indexed view when querying the base tables without an index hint.  There's a few others in there as well.